# Deriving a particular form of Stirling's Approximation of the Gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, gamma-function, upper-lower-bounds

I am working from some notes concerning bounds on Dedekind zeta functions and am trying to derive a supposed version of Stirling's approximation contained therein:

> Let $\sigma$ be fixed and $|t|\rightarrow \infty$, then a version of Stirling's approximation formula yields
>   $$|\Gamma(\sigma+it)| \sim |t|^{\sigma-\tfrac{1}{2}}e^{-\tfrac{\pi}{2}|t|}\ll |t|^{\sigma-\tfrac{1}{2}}e^{-|t|}$$
>   where we define
>   $$f(z)\ll g(z) \text{ iff } \exists c\in \mathbb{R}: \exists z_0\in \mathbb{C}: \forall |z|>|z_0|: |f(z)|<c|g(z)|$$

I started working from what appears to be the standard rendering of Stirling:
$$\Gamma(s)=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}s^{s-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^s}\big(1+O(\tfrac{1}{s})\big) \qquad \underset{\text{Since }O\big(\tfrac{1}{s}\big)\ll \tfrac{1}{s} \text{ by definition}}{\Rightarrow} \qquad \Gamma(s)\ll \Big|\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}s^{s-\frac{1}{2}}}{e^s}\Big|\cdot (1+|\tfrac{1}{s}|)$$
But making the relevant substitutions, shuffling things around, and ignoring the negligible contribution of $\sigma$ to the modulus when applicable, I have only been able to find
$$|\Gamma(\sigma+it)|\ll |t|^{\sigma-\tfrac{1}{2}}+|t|^{\sigma-\tfrac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: There should indeed be a decay behavior for large $t$, for example $|\Gamma(10+100i)|$ is less than $10^{-48}$. Intuitively this is caused by cancellations in the integral defining $\Gamma(\sigma+it)$ when $|t| \gg \sigma$.

Comment: @Ian I see what you mean and have edited the question. I will update if I find the answer you hint at.

Comment: It comes from $z^z=\exp(z \log(z))$. When $|t/\sigma|$ is large, $\log(z)$ has imaginary part close to $\pm \pi/2$ (with the same sign as $t$ has), so $z^z$ has a modulus not much bigger than $e^{-\pi/2 |t|}$.

Comment: @Ian Ah, thank you! If you care to write your comment in answer form I will mark it as accepted and upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decay comes from $z^z=\exp(z \log(z))$. When $|t/\sigma|$ is large, $\log(z)$ has imaginary part close to $\operatorname{sign}(t) \pi/2$, so that the real part of the exponent behaves like $\sigma \log(\sigma) - \pi/2 |t|$ which is dominated by the second term, giving the decay.